# Получить последнее непустое значение из массива php

Tags: php, массивы, for, foreach

У меня есть обычный массив, состоящий из 5-ти элементов:

```
$array = array('text1','text2','text3','','');
```

Где два последний пустые. Так же, у меня есть похожий массив, но с другим кол-вом пустых и не пустых значений:

```
$array = array('text1','text2','text3','text4','text5');
$array = array('text1','text2','','','');
```

Но мне всегда нужно получать только последний НЕпустой элемент из массива и его **индекс** в массиве.. Элементов в массивах всегда 5 - пустые и непустые.

Пожалуйста, подскажите как мне это сделать средствами php. Спасибо.

Comment: ну, цикл с конца массива не подойдёт?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, покажите пожалуйста пример. Можно так же с возможностью получить не только последний непустой элемент, но и его индекс в массиве. Спасибо.

Comment: А зачем нужно узнавать ключ последнего не пустого значения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Короткий, но не очень оптимальный вариант: очистить все пустые значения с помощью `array_filter` и взять последнее через `end`

```
$array = array_filter($array);
$lastValue = end($array);
```

Индекс можно получить спомощью функции `key()`, которая вернет ключ текущего элемента массива, а текущим, после вызова `end()`, будет как раз последний.

```
$clearedArray = array_filter($array);
$lastValue = end($clearedArray);
echo $lastValue; // значение

echo key($clearedArray); // индекс
```

---

Но оптимальнее будет обычным циклом, чтобы перебирать массив только один раз

```
$lastValue;
$lastValueIndex;

for ($i = count($array); $i > 0; --$i) {
    if (strlen($array[$i])) {
        $lastValue = $array[$i];
        $lastValueIndex = $i;
        break;
    }
}

// или 
//
// $lastValue;
// $lastValueIndex;
// for ($i = count($array); $i > 0; --$i, $lastValueIndex = $i, $lastValue = $array[$i]) {
//      if (!empty($array[$i])) {
//          break;
//      }
//  }    
// 
// или так (но это цикл от начала к концу, что может быть менее выгодно)
//
// $lastValue;
// $lastValueIndex;    
// for ($i = 0; !empty($array[$i]); $lastValueIndex = $i, $lastValue = $array[$i], ++$i);
// echo $lastValue;
// echo $lastValueIndex;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Еще вопрос. Я делаю импорт товаров. И это мне нужно для реализации вложенности товаров в категории. Загружается 5000 товаров. Метод array_filter будет актуален? Я просто фронт по большей части. Поэтому задаю такой вопрос. Возможно, глупый вопрос))

Comment: @s.kuznetsov нужно рассматривать вопрос шире, с детальными примерами. Так что это лучше новый вопрос создать. А в целом 5000 товаров обычно не загружают сразу.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский тут надо уточнить, что `array_search` вернет первый индекс, если в массиве могут быть совпадения, то результат может быть не совсем корректным, тогда лучше подходит вариант с циклом

Comment: @Tunker окей, щас дополню

Comment: а что, key() уже отменили?

Comment: но с циклом-то по-любому лучше

Comment: @s.kuznetsov, а как так получилось, что вместо 5 элементов вдруг стало 5000?

Comment: и как всегда лишнее empty(). когда уже вы научитесь ни пихать этот кривой оператор во все дыры

Comment: @Ипатьев критикуешь — предлагай, предлагаешь — делай!

Comment: Да, я тоже только что заметил что надо брать от $clearedArray. и заодно нашел что в 7.3 появилась array_key_last()

Comment: @Ипатьев эх, а я и забыл о нём.

Comment: Все таки, мне кажется, что вариант с циклом универсальнее, вариант с `key` красивый, но решает только по тем примерам, что привел автор вопроса, а если по тексту вопроса буквально т.е. `последний НЕпустой элемент из массива и его индекс` то при массиве `$array = array('text1','','text3','text4','');` (в массиве встречаются пустые значения не только в конце но и в середине к примеру) будет неверный результат

Comment: @Tunker вот кстати очень правильное замечание. array_filter поменяет ключи.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский посмотрел `array_filter` он может исказить даже на взгляд невинный массив `$array = array('0','1','2','3','');` - тоже будет ошибка, он отфильтрует первый 0 и пустые значения, индексы будут другие

Comment: @Tunker всё верно. расчёт именно на текст. а не замаскированный текст))